# Looping through Excel files and deleting the same column for each

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, walk

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd

#This nested for loop iterates through my excel files and then appends them to my list.
feature_classes = []
for dirpath, dirnames, datatypes in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,
                                                  datatype="Table"):
                                                  
    for datatype in datatypes:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

#This loop is intended to delete one column in each excel file. Currently It only deletes the column for the first file.
for fc in feature_classes:
        arcpy.management.DeleteField(os.path.join(dirpath, filename),"Delete_")
```

This code successfully deletes the field I want, but only from the first Excel file in the directory I am looping for. I think a nested for loop may be required but wanted to see what other simpler solutions may exist.

Comment: `dirpath` doesn't vary in the loop. You want to use `fc`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, there is no need for ArcPy:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

mainfolder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'
drop_column = 'CRY'

for root, folder, files in os.walk(mainfolder): #Will include all subfolders. If you dont want this use os.listdir
    for file in files:
        fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
        if os.path.isfile(fullname) and file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            df = pd.read_excel(fullname)
            df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col!=drop_column]] #Select all columns except drop column
            df.to_excel(fullname) #Will overwrite your original file
```